# What module do I need to import to use Anchor class in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I find that when I add the following line to my custom GWT widget
@UiField Anchor header;

I get a missing module error. I can't find documentation anywhere on what modules contain what. Can someone shed some light on what module I need to import to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

The Anchor is in base module, so if you have access to other GWT classes you should have access to it as well. So maybe you should check whether you haven't accidentally imported Anchor from other package. GWT Anchor should be from `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui`